# Performing code when pressing a button in an Android AppWidget

Tags: java, android, widget, android-appwidget

I am working on a small app that lets me specify a phonenumber and a message, and then quickly send the preset message to the preset number. I've got the main functionality up and running, and now I want to make a widget.

I've been playing around with various widget tutorials, but none have covered what I want to do. They all end up in either just updating a clock, or launching an activity. What I wish to do is simply sending a message when the button in my widget is pressed, maybe a little `Toast` to say "Message sent".

How do I add an `onClickListener` to the button without having to have it launch an activity?

My widget class looks pretty much like the example on the official dev guide

```
public class SaldoWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SaldoActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Updating Your Home Screen widget on Button Click You need to Register a custom broadcast receiver in Manifest and add it as action with widget.

Make Your Widget Clickable is four-five step task,it's not possible describe all steps here.so see [Android widget not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588080/android-widget-not-updating-has-incorrect-widget-id/10712961#10712961) my answer and download working home screen appwidget which generate random number on click from [HomeWidgetRendomNumber](https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/HomeWidgetRendomNumber.rar?attredirects=0&d=1).I Hope This Will Helpful...

Comment: if you have any problem in making appwidget click able then tell me i will help u.thanks

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at that answer and your code, and after wrapping my head around it, I got to the point where I get a Toast when clicking my button, so I think I'll manage to add the code for sending texts too. I am adding my code inside the if statement in onRecieve, though I am not sure if this is the right place for it.